# jquery-ui 1.9.1 autocomplete no droplist

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using a webservice to return my results but I get no result list even though I have data. The following is my code.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptContent" Runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="bldg">Your Buildings: </label>
    <input id="bldg" type="text" runat="server" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp
</div>
</asp:Content>


$("#bldg").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            async:false,
            url: "../../CommonWebServices/wsEntity.asmx/ReportBuildings",
            data: "{ 'Name': '" + request.term + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.Text,
                        value: item.Value
                    }   // end of return
                })) // end of response
            }   // end of success
        });     // end of ajax
    },  // end of source
    minLength: 1,
    //source:["apples","grapes", "granola","oranges","pumpkins"]
});
```

I am using the ui 1.9.1 and when the result is returned to the success I have records in data.d, but no drop list appears on the screen.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing my jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css. Once this was added my list showed up.